# Compute principal invariants for an extension of amount $\lambda$ in direction $\boldsymbol{e}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, tensors, classical-mechanics

I'm trying to solve an exercise taken from Gurtin's book (**Ex. 3 pg 52**)

> Let $f$ be an extension of amount $\lambda$ in direction $e$: $$f(p)=f(q)+U(p-q)$$
> where $$U = I + (\lambda  -1) e \otimes e$$ with $\lambda >0$ and $p,q$ are material points.
>
> Compute $C$ and the list of principal invariants $i_1(C),i_2(C),i_3(C)$, where $C$ is the right *Cauchy Green strain tensor* defined as $C=U^2$

---

First I compute $U^2$ explicitely:
$$U^2 =  (I + (\lambda  -1) e \otimes e ) (I + (\lambda  -1) e \otimes e ) = I + 2(\lambda -1) e \otimes e + (\lambda -1)^2 |e|^2 e \otimes e$$
I don't think I can simplify more, right?

To compute the invariants, I should use the fact that $C=U^2$ is symmetric and positive definite and hence the principal invariants are easy to compute because we only need the eigenvalues, but here I don't really know how I could move, because $e$ may be any direction, so it seems a really weird question.

---

**EDIT**
$$i_1(C)=\text{tr}(C)=\lambda^2$$

$$i_2(C)=\frac{1}{2}[\text{tr}(C)^2 - \text{tr(C^2)}]$$

Now $C^2 = U^2 U^2 = I+(\lambda^4 -1) e \otimes e$ and hence $$\text{tr}(C^2)=\text{tr}(U^4) = \lambda^4$$ so $$i_2(C)=\frac{1}{2}\lambda^2 (1 - \lambda^2 )$$

Finally, $$i_3(C)=\det(C)=\det(I + (\lambda -1) e \otimes e)$$

Now, $\det$ is the product of the eigenvalues, and we can see immediately that

- $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue: $$(I-(\lambda -1) e \otimes e)e = \lambda e$$
- all the other eigenvalues are $1$: take $v$ eigenvector, which is orthogonal to $e$ because $U$ is symmetric $$(I-(\lambda -1)e \otimes e)v = v - (\lambda-1) (e\otimes e) v=v$$ because $(e \otimes e )v = 0$

Therefore $$i_3(C) = \lambda 1= \lambda$$

Comment: If $\|e\|=1$ (a reasonable assumption since they mention the *direction* $e$), you get that $U^2 = I + (\lambda^2-1)e\otimes e$.

Comment: @IvoTerek You're right! That said, how can I infer something about the principal invariants?

Comment: If by "principal invariants" you mean eigenvalues of $U^2$, yes, sure. Use the formula $\det(I+B) = 1+{\rm tr}(B)$, valid when $B$ has rank $1$. Try to compute the characteristic polynomial of $U^2$ using this formula, where $B$ will be a certain multiple of $e\otimes e$.

Comment: Actually, by invariants I mean $$i_1(C)= \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3$$, $$i_2(C)= \frac{1}{2} [tr(C)-tr(C^2)]$$, $$i_3(C)=\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3$$

Of course $i_(C)= tr(C)$ and $i_3(C)= det(C)$, by linear algebra theory. For instance, $i_1(C)=\lambda^2$. But I can't compute the other two using you hint @IvoTerek

Comment: @IvoTerek I just edited my answer with a possible solution: could you please tell me if everything is okay now?

Comment: These invariants are the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of $U^2$, so use the hint and they'll pop up at the same time. You don't even need to find the eigenvalues themselves, it's even easier!

Comment: @IvoTerek I'm going to try again now, thanks. Btw, isn't my try in the "edit" correct?

Comment: No, actually computing $U^4$ seemed like overcomplicating it and I didn't feel like it. I hoped the hint would be enough, but I posted a computation as an answer. Watch for algebra mistakes, I did it quickly and haven't double-checked it.

Comment: I can immediately say that something is wrong in the edit, as $$\det(U^2) = \det(I + (\lambda^2-1)e\otimes e) = 1+{\rm tr}((\lambda^2-1)e\otimes e) = 1+\lambda^2-1 = \lambda^2 \neq \lambda,$$though.

Answer (score 1):

We have $U^2 = I + (\lambda^2-1)e\otimes e$. So the characteristic polynomial is $$\begin{align} \det(tI - U^2) &= \det((t-1)I - (\lambda^2-1)e\otimes e) \\ &= (t-1)^3 \det\left(I - \frac{\lambda^2-1}{t-1}e\otimes e\right) \\ &= (t-1)^3\left(1 - {\rm tr}\left(\frac{\lambda^2-1}{t-1}e\otimes e\right)\right) \\ &= (t-1)^3 \left(1 - \frac{(\lambda^2-1)}{t-1} \right) \\ &= (t-1)^3 - (\lambda^2-1)(t-1)^2 \\ &{\color{red}{= (t-1)^2(t-\lambda^2)}} \\ &= (t^2-2t+1)(t-\lambda^2) \\ &= t^3 - (\lambda^2+2)t^2 + (2\lambda^2+1)t - (\lambda^2). \end{align}$$It seems that the invariants are $\lambda^2+2$, $2\lambda^2+1$ and $\lambda^2$.

Comment: It's almost everything clear, thanks. Just one last thing: for $e \otimes e$ you intend the matrix with entries $e_i e_j$, right? @IvoTerek

Comment: Yes. But you had this notation yourself even before I had already used it...